# Error "The syntax of the command is incorrect" when renaming a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I get this error on this step of my SQL 2005 process:

```
rename "G:\AuthorsList\AuthorsList_New.mdb""G:\AuthorsList\AuthorsListCopy.mdb"
```

I am trying to rename the file.  I have also tried this and get the same error:

```
rename "G:\AuthorsList\AuthorsList_New.mdb" "G:\AuthorsList\AuthorsListCopy.mdb"
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: What is "SL 2005"? Are you expecting SQL Server to rename a file as if you were calling this at the command prompt?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I corrected my error  - it should be SQL 2005.  The above is the last step of a three step SQL 2005 DTS package.  I am using the Operating System (cmdexec) type to run this step of the package.

Comment: Which error ? any error message ? you have to activate cmdexec in SQL config

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check the documentation for the [rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren?view=sc-vmm-1801) command:

> **Syntax**
>   `rename [Drive:][Path]filename1 filename2`
>
> **Parameters**
>   `[Drive:][Path]filename1`: Specifies the location and name of the file or set of files you want to rename. FileName1 can include wildcard characters (* and ?).
>   `filename2`: Specifies the new name for the file. You can use wildcard characters to specify new names for multiple files.

The second parameter cannot be a path, it should contain only the new filename:

```
rename "G:\AuthorsList\AuthorsList_New.mdb" AuthorsListCopy.mdb
```

Comment: Hi, i want to use this:  rename %userprofile%\.ssl "*.exe2" "a.exe" but it returns syntax error. what do you recommend?

Comment: @Arash There should be 2 parameters and you specified 3.

Comment: I want to add more note here, renaming file, cannot has space.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I extracted files from a zip to the directory, the files went to different directory created in the zip process.

That is, the were no files in the directory that ren *.* *.sql was run on.

Changed directories to the new dir created by zip and it worked.